# ios building Error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, intel

I have a problem in intel xdk ios build, I am also showing log file below.

**BUILD FAILED**

The following build commands failed:

> Check dependencies
>   (1 failure)
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,babysigning.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,babysigning,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,babysigning.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,babysigning,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=.../cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Please help me to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resolved !!! this happens due to the Provisioning profile apple id not matching with bundle identifier, so to resolve this error i have used wildcard char(*)in app id during creation of Provisioning file in apple developer account.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you did this?

Comment: @Manas - Any more information you could provide on how you fixed this error would be welcome, as I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Gareth Jones, I too am having this problem.  Were you able to resolve the issue?  Can you all provide any more details on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @CaptainSkubalon I didn't manage to solve it directly - I've found that the iOS platform/project is a little buggy. After a bit of messing around, I basically just removed the whole iOS platform (as in, cordova platform remove ios), re-installed my dependencies, and started from scratch.

This time around Cordova seemed to generate the 'correct' iOS platform files. My advice would just be to play around with the platform; re-add it/re-gen the iOS project. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I want to point out (as it was a bit of a challenge to write around): When I say 'project' I'm meaning the iOS platform NOT your entire application :) Cordova generates an XCode project, which is what I found to be the issue - I'd open it and there would be something wrong, such as a missing dependency. My advice is to not try and fix that via xcode but instead try and get Cordova to generate the XCode project "correctly" - It tends to come down to making sure all the dependencies are up to date and installed correctly

Comment: Thanks @GarethJones, I ended up solving it to.  I went to my last known working copy out of source control and copied my www files into it.  Frustrating.